# ER_NOT_SUPPORTED_AUTH_MODE - MySQL server

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, linux, configuration

### Failed at Connecting `Node.js Server` to `MySQL-Database`

---

I had **MariaDB"** installed on a **"Node.js Server"**, but decided that I wanted to use a SQL Database instead. I uninstalled, and completely removed **"MariaDB"**, after which, I proceeded to install the *"Community Ed." **"MySQL Database"**. After going through the entire **'MySQL Setup Process'***, I made several attempts to connect to the database via a JavaScript document that implemented the de facto code snippet for a JS DB Connection — *my DB-connection document is posted as a code snippet bellow* — shown in the code snippet bellow*. Disappointingly, the JS/SQL connection failed at each attempt.

##### Here is the Failed Connection Error Message that I received:

---

```
"ER_NOT_SUPPORTED_AUTH_MODE: Client does not support authentication
protocol requested by server. Consider upgrading MariaDB client."
```

##### JS/SQL Connection Snippet that I am using:

---

```
    var mysql = require('mysql');
    
    var connection = mysql.createConnection({
        host     : 'localhost',
        user     : 'root',
        password : '********',
        database : 'foobarDb'
    });
```

Comment: Downgrading MYSQL ver 8.0.13 to ver 5.7.24.0 solved it for me.

Comment: similar to question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50093144/mysql-8-0-client-does-not-support-authentication-protocol-requested-by-server

Comment: detailed explanation for this error when using mysqljs/mysql, see post https://stackoverflow.com/a/56509065/9905745

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I figure that some MySQL versions have the authentication for the establishment of a connection a bit messed up. All I had to do was add the line `"insecureAuth" : true` to the `CreateConnection(...)` credentials.

```
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : 'localhost',
  user     : 'root',
  password : '********',
  database : 'vod_bill_database',
  insecureAuth : true
});
```

The error is gone now, and the client is successfully connecting.

Comment: Doesn't work with mysql 8.0 on ubuntu, because it's (at this comment's date) still unsupported by mysql.js.

Comment: DO NOT USE THIS CONFIGURATION!!! This method is to maintain compatibility for versions that require for the old, and very insecure, method of authentication. Where this hack may, or may not work, it is an `INSECURE` method to authenticate, and should be avoided whenever possible. This should be blatantly obvious considering the name. Here is the link to the API, and connection options if you want to see for your self. https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql#connection-options

Answer (score 144):

For MySQL v8.0 use the following:

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password'
```

Comment: seems to reset the schema level credentials for your database.

Comment: should disable skip-grant-tables first

Comment: This answer doesn't quite make sense because it was taken from the context of this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50093144/mysql-8-0-client-does-not-support-authentication-protocol-requested-by-server. I recommend just looking at it instead of this post.

Comment: I see this post for the first time, do something practical ...

Comment: We should replace 'root' with our username and 'password' with the password we want to assign. Once done please FLUSH PRIVILEGES; in order to activate it.

Answer (score 46):

You can use the package `mysql2` instead of `mysql`. I ran into the same issue and using `mysql2` worked for me.

You can install this package using `npm i mysql2`

Comment: totally perfect solution - thx

Comment: This is the right answer! Changing the database server is a workaround not solution. MySQL 8 uses new authentication protocol. mysql2 supports the new protocol but mysqljs/mysql does not.

Comment: This worked like magic !! Thank you Just installed mysql2 and only changed this `import mysql=require("mysql2")`

Comment: such an underrated answer, works like a charm

Answer (score 33):

[image]

You need to reconfigure the `Quick Action Settings` by clicking the **"Reconfigure Link"** as shown in the screenshot below. From there, select ***"Legacy password"*** for `v5.1`.

##### The cause of the error:

---

You installed the latest **"MySQL *Version*"**, `v8.0`. The latest version has a different encryption plugin for authenticating users at login. 5.6, and 5.1 revert to the prior encryption algorithms. Please note, [`5.6` & `5.1` have several security vulnerabilities reported by oracle](https://www.oracle.com/security-alerts/cpuoct2014verbose.html#MSQL).

Comment: I was using the terminal to run and manage my database, so this was not an option. Thanks though ;)

Comment: this worked for me, but only after I created a new user and connection in the MySql workbench. I cannot get it working with an existing connection. But good enough for now. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 25):

The top-rated answers in this Q/A thread are for the most part valid, but they are unorganized, which is to say the least. A solution is here, however, the solution is bits and pieces amongst three other answers. To offer an answer that is a single solution, more helpfull, and is a time saver, I'll make an attempt to write an answer myself in a way that is clear, concise, and orderly. I will cover the whole problem that **Ubuntu** users experiance, and in addition, I will add information that's helpfull, and not included in any other answer, that will help readers understand the issue that persist for them.

#### To Start: The Issue is not a SQL Problem, it is an Ubuntu Problem

The issue that persist for you, has to do with the fact (a fact most software developers/I.T. professionals are probably all already aware of) the **`'ROOT'`** user doesn't have a password in Ubuntu, and is accessible by anyone with `$ sudo` privileges. To offer clarity for anyone experiencing this issue who might be new to some of the semantics that I am throwing out there; Ubuntu users use the ***`sudo -i`***  command to register as the **Root-user**, whereas, every other Linux distribution in existence uses a **User-ID w/ a Password**. In truth, I cannot remember ever needing to be a ROOT user for anything other than Database Management, and always only when I am first installing a Database to a server, though my experience is probably far limited in comparison to some IT professionals out there. My point is, typically using `sudo` for everything does the Job, but in this case it is problematic, so the important thing to note is the following:

##### PROBLEM:

---

Ubuntu lacks a 'ROOT PASSWORD' and this is why everyone experiencing the issue that we are discussing runs a Distribution of the Ubuntu OS/SHELL. And unless we rewrite the Ubuntu kernel, and the practically everything else in the operating system, we cannot give Ubuntu SHELL a *"root password"*.

###### SOLUTION:

---

We may not be able to give the Ubuntu SHELL a root password, but we can, and we will, give **MySQL** a `'ROOT PASSWORD'`.

---

##### TO EXECUTE THE SOLUTION YOU NEED TO HAVE THE FOLLOWING:

1. Node.js v12+
2. NPM (Probably need v5+ but don't quote me on that)
3. MySQL v8.0+ (obviously)
4. The MySQL Driver (from npm)

###### CONFIRMATION:

---

###### *If you don't already have everything on the list you honestly can't say that this is the issue your dealing with.*

###### *If you do have everything on the list*

and you are running an Ubuntu distro, then you should be getting an error message that probably looks somthing like the one I got when I had to fix this issue.

###### My error message read:

```
ERROR: (28000): Access denied for user 'ajc'@'localhost' 
ERROR: ERROR_NOT_SUPPORTED_AUTH_MODE: Client does not support
authentication protocol requested by server; consider upgrading 
MySQL client

'Client does not support authentication protocol requested by server; consider upgrading MySQL client
```

###### If your still reading then your likely in the right place.

1. To start fixing the problem create an empty **Node.js** project, and install the MySQL driver as a dependency to it using NPM (you should know how to do this, as you had to do that to have this issue). Add a JavaScript `.js` file. Call the file, `sqltest.js` or whatever something like that.
2. Add the code below to the file you just created.

```
let mysql = require('mysql');

let connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host     : 'localhost',
    user     : 'root',
    password : '********',
    database : 'DB_App_00',
});

connection.connect(function(err) {
    if (err) {
      return console.error('error: ' + err.message);
    }
  
    console.log('Connected to the MySQL server.');
  });
```

3. In the method called 'createConnection' is a JSON OBJ parameter holding the credential values to make a valid connection to the **MySQL** database server. The user has to equal to 'root', and the database has to exist. Also for a later test add a testing table to the database, with some BS data."
4. Now open a terminal window, and do your typical updates & upgrades, this is important, which is why every tutorial asks you to do them.

```
~$: sudo apt update
~$: sudo apt upgrade
```

5. After you do your upgrades enter the following command into your terminal:

```
~$: sudo mysql -u root
```

6. It should prompt you for your Ubuntu Password, type it and [ENTER].

###### The next step is critically important:

7. Now here is the step that could be considered the medicine and/or the cure to the problem. Your terminal should be open, and you should be inside of the MYSQL Server, under the user 'root'. The terminal should have the cursor flashing at a blank mysql command-line. Within the CMDL copy & paste this:

```
mysql> ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'ChoosePassword';

mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

8. The next part is obvious, change 'ChoosePassword' to a password you will remember while leaving the password within single quotation marks. Change absolutely nothing else, press [ENTER]
9. If you followed the steps correctly, you now have a MySQL 'ROOT USER' with its own password now. Test it by copy and paste the following at the Ubuntu CMDL:

```
 ~$: mysql -u root -p
```

- It will prompt you for your new password, type it and [ENTER]

...you should be in, now exit.

```
mysql>exit
```

10. Back to your 'testsql.js' file, alter the credentials to root for the user, password to your password, a valid database, and host to localhost, unless you have a unique need for a different hostname.

```
let connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host     : 'localhost',
    user     : 'root',
    password : '********',
    database : 'DB_App_00',
});
```

11. now use node to run the node test file

```
~$: node testsql.js
```

###### Final Thought:

If it doesn't say connected you did something wrong, but if all went well, you should connect. It took some effort before I got it to work, but this answer should save you some time from reading all the other half written answers.

Comment: Is it still/really *an UBUNTU problem* if I am getting it on MacOS?

Comment: @IanMbae I should have been more clear. This issue can pop-up for others, but typically it is easily resolved by logging into the "ROOT USER", however, ***Ubuntu*** doesn't ship with an accessible Root user account. I believe MacOS has a root user though. Now, I am far from a unix specialist, especially when it comes to mac. I guess I would have a couple questions at this point, which would be... Are you able to login to ROOT on MacOS, and if so can you fix the problem as the root user? If you can't login to root, or fix the issue as root, then the answer needs to be edited.

Answer (score 10):

You can either alter an existing user to use mysql_native_password, or create a new user,

```
CREATE USER 'new_user'@'%' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY '***';
GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'new_user'@'%';
ALTER USER 'new_user'@'%' REQUIRE NONE WITH MAX_QUERIES_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_CONNECTIONS_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_UPDATES_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_USER_CONNECTIONS 0;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `new_user`.* TO 'new_user'@'%';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

replace new_user with your new user name, and set your password.

Now you can access mysql from node using the mysql package,

```
 npm install mysql
```

recommended to use pool connection for this package.

Answer (score 6):

1st run this code ->

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password';
```

2nd

```
flush privileges;
```

Answer (score 0):

**try the older version of mysql like 5.6.40**, it uses by default SHA256_password auth where new version 8.0. uses by default sha2_password auth which is more secure and throw this ***authentication protocol error***.
[MYSQL installer 5.6.40](https://dev.mysql.com/get/Downloads/MySQLInstaller/mysql-installer-web-community-5.6.40.1.msi)

Answer (score 0):

yellow yow bros !

```js
// mysql.ts
const pool = mysql.createPool({
    connectionLimit: 10,
    host: "localhost",
    user: "root",
    password: "password",
    database: "rest-resume-api",
});
```

and then I have a docker-compose file such as

```
# docker-compose.yml

version: '3.3'

services:
  db:
    image: mysql
    restart: always
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: 'rest-resume-api'
      MYSQL_USER: 'root'
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'password'
    ports:
      - '3306:3306'
    expose:
      - '3306'
    volumes:
      - my-db:/var/lib/mysql2
volumes:
  my-db:
```

Comment: It did help me, i appreciate it!

Comment: If anyone using docker. This is correct. Worked for me

Answer (score 0):

you can do it

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password'

ALTER USER 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password'

FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

check mysql root user IDENTIFIED

```
select user,host,plugin from user;

+------------------+-----------+-----------------------+
| user             | host      | plugin                |
+------------------+-----------+-----------------------+
| root             | %         | mysql_native_password |
| mysql.infoschema | localhost | caching_sha2_password |
| mysql.session    | localhost | caching_sha2_password |
| mysql.sys        | localhost | caching_sha2_password |
| root             | localhost | mysql_native_password |
+------------------+-----------+-----------------------+
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : 'localhost',
  user     : 'root',
  password : '********',
  database : 'vod_bill_database',
  port : 3308 
});
```

I had the same error and since i changed my port in phpmyadmin from 3306 to 3308 therefore here also i had to write port: 3308 and it started working.

Answer (score -1):

in order to overcome this error use the following code:

```
var connectionString = 'mysql://*root:*password@*localhost/*database?charset=utf8_general_ci&timezone=-0700'; 
var connection= mysql.createConnection(connectionString);
```

but make sure that you changed the * marks in the connectionString based on your setup.

Answer (score -2):

just create a new user on MySQL

```
CREATE USER 'foo'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'bar';
```