# Syntax Error when trying to reset Root password in MariaDB shell

Tags: node.js, linux, mariadb

I have installed MariaDB-server(10.1.34) freshly on Linux Ubuntu 18.04

I have started a SQL shell with:

```
sudo -i
mysql -uroot -p -h localhost
```

The shell opens.
I want to change my password to be compatible with Node.js typeorm and mysql driver(as I always get this [error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44946270/er-not-supported-auth-mode-mysql-server)) with the following:

```
ALTER USER root@localhost IDENTIFIED BY '12345';
```

And it always says I have an error in my syntax but I checked online and it's even on MariaDBs [ALTER USER site](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/alter-user/). What is going wrong here?
I tried:

```
ALTER USER root@localhost IDENTIFIED BY '12345';
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '12345';
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY '12345';
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH 'mysql_native_password' BY '12345';
ALTER USER root@localhost IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY '12345';
```

But nothing works. I always get a syntax error, but I don't know where I made a mistake. Can someone point out my mistake?

Answer (score 0):

From  https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/alter-user/ :

> The ALTER USER statement was introduced in MariaDB 10.2.0.

See also the older `SET PASSWORD`: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/set-password/