# Connect JavaScript running in docker container to MySQL database running on another docker container

Tags: mysql, node.js, docker

I'm currently running a local instance of RocketChat and the RocketBot using docker-compose and a corresponding docker-compose.yaml file:

I use the standard mysql module like this:

```
var con = mysql.createConnection({
    host: '<placeholder>',
    user: 'root',
    port: '3306',
    password: '<placeholder>',
});
```

The host, user, port and password are gathered from running the inspect command on the container containing the MySQL server. The MySQL does work as  I can run it and make changes to it and even connect to it using MySQL workbench. I get this error:

```
rosbot_1              | [Tue Jun 18 2019 18:42:06 GMT+0000 (UTC)] ERROR Error: connect ETIMEDOUT
rosbot_1              |     at Connection._handleConnectTimeout (/home/hubot/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:412:13)
```

I have no idea how to proceed now, how can I connect from the bot served by docker-compose to the MySQL container using JavaScript?

EDIT:

docker-compose.yaml:

```
version: '2.1'

services:
  mongo:
    image: mongo:3.2
    hostname: 'mongo'
    volumes:
     - ./db/data:/data/db
     - ./db/dump:/dump
    command: mongod --smallfiles --oplogSize 128 --replSet rs0

  mongo-init-replica:
    image: mongo:3.2
    command: 'mongo mongo/rocketchat --eval "rs.initiate({ _id: ''rs0'', members: [ { _id: 0, host: ''localhost:27017'' } ]})"'
    links:
      - mongo:mongo

  rocketchat:
    image: rocketchat/rocket.chat:latest
    hostname: 'rocketchat'
    volumes:
      - ./rocketchat/uploads:/app/uploads
    environment:
      - PORT=3000
      - ROOT_URL=http://localhost:3000
      - MONGO_URL=<placeholder>
      - MONGO_OPLOG_URL=<placeholder>
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "-f", "http://localhost:3000"]
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
    links:
      - mongo:mongo
    ports:
      - 3000:3000

  <placeholder>:
    image: <placeholder>
    hostname: "<placeholder>"
    environment:
      - ROCKETCHAT_URL=<placeholder>
      - ROCKETCHAT_ROOM=""
      - ROCKETCHAT_USER=<placeholder>
      - ROCKETCHAT_PASSWORD=<placeholder>
      - ROCKETCHAT_AUTH=<placeholder>
      - BOT_NAME=<placeholder>
      - LISTEN_ON_ALL_PUBLIC=true
      - EXTERNAL_SCRIPTS=hubot-help,hubot-seen,hubot-links,hubot-diagnostics,hubot-pugme,hubot-reload
      - PENTEXT_PATH=/home/hubot/pentext
      - ADDITIONAL_PACKAGES=mysql,lodash
      - RESPOND_TO_LIVECHAT=true
      - RESPOND_TO_DM=true
    depends_on:
      rocketchat:
        condition: service_healthy
    links:
      - rocketchat:rocketchat
    volumes:
      - <placeholder>
    ports:
      - 3001:3001
```

Comment: Choudl you share the docker-compose.yml file ?

Comment: Have added it to the question, have redacted some of the sensitive stuff that contained the names of the project in question. The <placeholder> refers to the bot in the rocket chat.

Comment: It looks like the mysql container is not a standalone container or is not part of this docker-compose configuration. Is mysql in another container, or is included in some container listed in your file?

Comment: @F.Igor I'm running the MySQL server in another docker container yes not in this docker-compose file.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, you can connect to another container using the container name as hostname:

If you have a container with mysql, the container name (in this example 'db') is the host name to access the mysql container (also, you can use a `hostname: 'mysqlhostname'` to specify a different name):

```
db:
    image: mysql
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: mypass
      MYSQL_DATABASE: mydb
```

In your rocketchat container you should add some environment variables for mysq root password and database to make it available to your container

```
rocketchat:
    image: rocketchat/rocket.chat:latest
    hostname: 'rocketchat'
    volumes:
      - ./rocketchat/uploads:/app/uploads
    environment:
      - PORT=3000
      - ROOT_URL=http://localhost:3000
      - MONGO_URL=<placeholder>
      - MONGO_OPLOG_URL=<placeholder>
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: mypass
      - MYSQL_DATABASE: mydb
      - MYSQL_HOSTNAME: db
    ...
    links:
      - rocketchat:rocketchat 
      - db : db
```

And then, use the host name and the environment variables to create your connection:

```
var con = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'db', // or process.env.MYSQL_HOSTNAME
    user: 'root',
    port: '3306',
    password: 'mypass', // or process.env.MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
});
```

Comment: When I add this I get the error: ERROR Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.1:3306. I also had to add quotation marks around the new arguments for it to even serve the file.

Comment: I forgot to add the host to the "links" section (now i've edited to add db in `links:` section of the example)

Comment: I now seem to get a different errror: ERROR Error: ER_NOT_SUPPORTED_AUTH_MODE. I get this error if I don't add the variables to the environment under rocketchat. Thanks for the help thus far, I would be lost without it.

Comment: If you are getting errors related to authentication modes in mysql, you should check the docker mysql reference to modify some authentication parameters. For example, adding `command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password` (see https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql)

Comment: Additionally, check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44946270/er-not-supported-auth-mode-mysql-server for a different solution (modifying the root user to use native password)