# How to connect to MySQL server from Visual Studio Code

Tags: mysql, sql, visual-studio-code

I recently downloaded the MySQL server and want to connect to it using VSCode, after i installed the VSCode extension, i still have little idea on how to connect to the server/database. All the guides online seem to cover Visual Studio C++.

Comment: You can use SQLTools, https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mtxr.sqltools , there will be DB icon on left, and new connection, just follow the steps... It supports 5 major DB's

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you install the plugin vscode-database you have some buttons in the footer menu bar to connect to your database. When you open the plugin there is a short tutorial how to connect.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bajdzis.vscode-database

Comment: `Client does not support authentication protocol requested by server; consider upgrading MySQL client` I get this error

Comment: EDIT:fixed by https://stackoverflow.com/a/50547109/13213725

Answer (score 0):

Use this extension. I tried many of them but they didn't seem to connect.

- Make sure you first have downloaded *MySQL Community Server* on your machine.
- Then go ahead and temporarily download Workbench just to easily get the credentials for your connection.
- Then use this [cweijan.vscode-mysql-client2](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=cweijan.vscode-mysql-client2&ssr=false#review-details) extension!

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Been a while, but for those encountering the issue and who are trying to connect to a remote server with a SSL certificate, I recommend the extension MySQL management tool (by Jun Han).

Other popular extensions I tried didn't have an option to insert the path to the certificate (such as SQL Tool).

After installing it, it will appear on the File Explorer Menu. You then have to click the "+" button to add a connection, and it will prompt you for the host, password, and path to the certificate. Pretty straightforward.

My database is a MySQL 8.0 hosted on Azure.