# MySQL error: ER_NOT_SUPPORTED_AUTH_MODE: Client does not support authentication protocol requested by server; consider upgrading MySQL client

Tags: mysql, node.js, nodejs-server

Could someone tell what error "ER_NOT_SUPPORTED_AUTH_MODE: Client does not support authentication protocol requested by server; consider upgrading MySQL client" means?

**My code:**

```js
var mysql = require('mysql');

var con = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "localhost",
  user: "user",
  password: "password",
  database: 'database'
});

con.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) throw 'THE ERROR IS: ' + err;
  console.log("Connected!");
});
```

Comment: do you tried that solution? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44946270/er-not-supported-auth-mode-mysql-server

Comment: Could you say the answer?

Answer (score 1):

I also faced the same issue but the error **got resolved** by using **mysql2 instead of mysql.**
so type

```
npm install mysql2
```

in your terminal.
and update your code with

```
const mysql = require("mysql2");
```

Answer (score 0):

In the link that I sent for you, was added this property: `insecureAuth : true`.

```
var con = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "localhost",
  user: "user",
  password: "password",
  database: 'database',
  insecureAuth : true

});
```

Comment: Try this: 

`sudo mysql -u root -p`
`ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'ChoosePassword';`
`FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`